# How to 'split' a Spring web application into several applications/services

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring web application that consists of the following parts:

- Web GUI for Users
- Background processes
- Webservice-like API

It's all in one application. For every update, the whole application has to be stopped and redeployed, which of course means that all users are kicked out and the API is temporarily unavailable.

I am wondering whether there a ways to seperate the application into several applications/services which could be deployed seperately. All applications would need access to the DAOs and to several utility classes/services.

I know there will be no ready-made solution for this. But maybe you can show some 'best practice examples' or show me some direction where I could go.

Answer (score 0):

But if some part of the application is offline while redeployment, the complete application will not work, so this is likely that the split is not the solution.

If the problem is just that the users session is killed, then you should have a look at values stored in the session that are not able to been serialized.

If your probem is that the application is offline for some time, then you need a second server and some switch (loadbalancer) to implement a [blue-green-deployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)